# How do I get my "show" page to render?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I have Rails 5 installed.  I'm having trouble getting my show page to render.  My rake routes has this

votes_show GET    /votes/show(.:format)              votes#show

Then in my app/controllers/votes_controller.rb file I have

```
  def show
    id = params[:id]
    # If there is no person selected based on the param, choose one randomly
    if !id.present?
      @person = Person.order("RANDOM()").limit(1).first
    else
      @person = Person.find(:id => params[:id])
    end
```

but when I go to http://localhost:3000/votes/1, I get a

```
No route matches [GET] "/votes/1"
```

error.  I'm missing something real obvious.  What is it?

Comment: Your `rake routes` should show `GET    /votes/:id(.:format)    votes#show`.
add your `routes.rb` file to the question.

Comment: How did you create the show route?

Comment: @hashrocket, I added "get 'votes/show'" to my config/routes.rb file.

Comment: Are you using RESTful routes?

Comment: That's the only thing I have in my config/routes.rb file pertaining to my "votes" controller.  Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: Try putting resources :votes in your routes.rb file and deleting what you already have there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
votes_show GET /votes/show(.:format) votes#show
```

this line is telling rails that "when you see a route that is `/votes/show` then go to the `VotesController#show` method."

When you then type in `/votes/1`, rails is checking that against the routes and not finding a route that looks like that... it is specifically looking *only* for `/votes/show`

As mentioned in the comments, you must add a line like:

```
get '/votes/:id(.:format)', to: 'votes#show'
```

or better yet, use resourceful routes like

```
resources :votes
```

Comment: I assume I'm adding "GET /votes/:id(.:format) votes#show" to my config/routes.rb file?  If so, I tried this and got the error, "syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)" and its pointing at the ":id" portion of the line.

Comment: The example was a general description (like pseudocode), not exactly what you needed to type into your routes file. Here is Rails' routing guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html it'll give you a better overview of how this all works. Specifically, you probably need to use `get '/votes/:id(.:format)', to: 'votes#show'` (In answers, we often assume some knowledge... I'll update my answer to reflect this change)